# Does IE setting "do not save encrypted pages to disk" prevent caching within same browser session as well?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, ssl

I've an ASP.NET application served over HTTPS. I noticed in the logs that none of my resources files (CSS/Images/JS/XSL) are being served with a 304 header, which they should since I'm sending necessary headers correctly.

Client's browser settings are:

Check for newer versions of stored pages: 'Automatically'

Disk space to use: 65

Days to keep page in history: 7

**Do not save encrypted pages to disk:checked on**

I assume its the last setting that is preventing the user's browser to use the cached files. Is that correct? But I've seen fresh copies of same file being requested in the same session as well. So my question is that does "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" feature prevents HTTPS caching within same browser session as well? If yes, is there a way to deal with it other than serving static pages through another sub domain w/o SSL?

Thanks for your help!

PS: I noticed an interesting thing. We also have an emptu.html file (that is more like a static placeholder) that is served over the same SSL and for that file status code is ALWAYS 304. If caching is not allowed over SSL due to client settings then how come that file is being used from browser cache for the same user?